# Pick random integer between $2$ and $100$, expected value of the number of primes that divide $n$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, expected-value

> Sally picks a random integer $n$ between $2$ and $100$. What is the expected value of the number of primes that divide $n$?

I think the answer is$$\sum_{\text{primes }p \text{ where }2 \le p \le 97} {{\text{# of those divisible by }p\text{ from }2\text{ to }100 \text{ (inclusive)}}\over{99}}$$Computing the first few terms, I get$${50\over{99}} + {{33}\over{99}} + {{20}\over{99}} + {{14}\over{99}} + \ldots$$
However, I'm lazy and I'm wondering if there is a quicker way to finish solving this problem without having to calculate every single last term and add them all up.

Comment: Do you pick with or without replacement?

Comment: Note that $\left\lfloor\frac{100}{2}\right\rfloor = 50$, $\left\lfloor\frac{100}{3}\right\rfloor = 33$, $\left\lfloor\frac{100}{5}\right\rfloor = 20$ and so on.  I don't know how you were calculating $50,33,20,14,\dots$ but it shouldn't take too long.  Once you get to the primes between $33$ and $50$ those contribute $2$, once you get to the primes $51$ to $99$ those contribute $1$.

Comment: As for writing this as a sum like you had, that is absolutely correct and follows from the linearity of expectation.

Comment: It looks like it can be approximated by $\frac{100}{99}\sum\frac1p\approx\frac{100}{99}\ln(\ln(101))$

Comment: [wolfram calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+k%3D1+to+25+of+floor%28100%2Fprime%28k%29%29%2F99)

Comment: pari/gp code: `P = primes(25); sum(k=1, 25, floor(100/P[k])) / 99` - which delivers $19/11$. Why should we compute this with bare hands? (And who is Sally?)

Comment: "It looks like it can be approximated by 10099∑1p≈10099ln(ln(101))"  I'd say for small numbers like $n=100$ that that is not really accurate enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primes $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97$ ($25$ of) of them have one prime factor. But so do the powers of primes.  $4,8,16,32,64, 9, 27,81,25,49$ so $10$ of those so there are $35$ numbers with one prime factor.

If we take those with $1$ prime factors and multiply by a prime that isn't a factor to get a number with $2$ prime factors we get.

$2 \times 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 9,27,25,49$ are $18$ such numbers. (Tally $18$ number with 2 prime factors.  $53$ numbers total.)

$4\times 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23,9, 25$ are $10$ such numbers.($28$ with 2 factors. $63$ total)

$8\times 3,5,7,11,9$ are $5$ such numbers.($33$, $68).

$16\times 3,5$ are $2$ such numbers. ($35,70$)

$32\times 3$ is $1$.($36,71$)

$3\times  7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31,25$ are $9$ such numbers.($45,80$)

$9\times 7,11$ are $2$ such numbers. ($47,82$)

And $27\times 5> 10$ so there are no more powers of $3$ to consider.

$5\times 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19$ are$7$ more.($54,89$)

$7\times 11,13$ are the last $2$. Any more would be the product of $2$ primes over $10$.($56,91$)

So there are $56$ numbers with $2$ factors.

That accounts for $91$ of the $99$ numbers.  There are only $8$ with $3$ or more factors.

They are $2\times 3\times 5, 4\times 3\times 5, 2\times 9\times 5,2\times 3\times 7, 4\times 3\times 7, 2\times 3\times 11,2\times 3\times 13,2\times 5\times 7$

And so there are $35 + 2\times 56 + 3\times 8 = 171$ prime factors spread among $99$ numbers.

The expected value of the number of prime factors of $n$ is $\frac {171}{99}$.

Comment: Argh... spent to long working on that. Keith Backman did the same thing but didn't waste time calculating the just majority of those with $2$ primes.

Answer (score 1):

There are $25$ primes smaller than $100$. In addition, there are $10$ numbers that are powers of primes smaller than $100$: $4,8,9,16,25,27,32,49,64,81$. In total, there are $35$ numbers between $2$ and $100$ inclusive that have only one prime factor.

Since $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot7=210>100$, there are no numbers in that range which have four or more prime factors. There are $8$ numbers in that range which have three prime factors: $30,42,60,66,70,78,84,90$. You can either count those which have two prime factors, or calculate that number as $99-35-8=56$.

A randomly chosen number has $\frac{35}{99}$ chance of having $1$ prime factor, $\frac{56}{99}$ chance of having $2$ prime factors, and $\frac{8}{99}$ chance of having $3$ prime factors.

The expected number of prime factors would be $1\cdot\frac{35}{99}+2\cdot\frac{56}{99}+3\cdot\frac{8}{99}=\frac{171}{99}$, or between $1$ and $2$, with a slight bias towards $2$.